# Why can't I update my imovie?

Tags: macos, software-update, imovie

I can't update my iMovie - it always says "These apps cannot be accepted by your Apple ID" anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

Apple covers accepting the apps that come bundled (like iMovie):

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203658

It depends on checking that someone else has "accepted" the apps and calling support if no one has accepted them and you don't want to lose them.